# Google translate API with annotations

Tags: google-translate

When using the Google Translate API, it just returns one translation for a given word. For example, when I let it translate the English word "hide" to Italian, it just responds with "nascondere".

However, Google Translate on the web offers much more: they don't just show one translation (or list of possible translations), but also the frequency as well as the precise meaning of a specific translation:

[image]

I'd like to get these results via an API.

**Is there a public API that offers the same results?**

Of course, I could just use [the endpoint `/translate_a/single`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8085743/google-translate-vs-translate-api) that is used by the Google Translate website. But this endpoint does not include an API key, so if I send too many requests, they will most likely block me.

Also, the endpoint `/translate_a/single` returns many fields of which I do not know the precise meaning, so its usage would most likely involve some reverse engineering.

Comment: getting access to the frequency would be super helpful in my case.